# set text to div tag from asp.net

Tags: html, asp.net, css

See the code:

```
<li>
    <div class="evnt-date">31<span>July</span> 
    </div>
    <div class="event-info"> <span><i class="icon-time"></i> 12:25 PM</span>

        <p>Anim pariatur cliche repreh enderit, enim eiusmod high life</p>
    </div>
</li>
```

i want to change the 31 and july value, how can i do that in asp.net

that code come from a html with css page, i try to mod it.
thank for read :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to change the text from code-behind file.

use asp.net label with attribut `runat=server`:

```
<asp:Literal ID="date" runat="server" Text='31' />
```

and in your code:

```
date.Text = "updated text";
```

so try this:

```
<li> 
  <div class="evnt-date"> 
    <asp:Literal ID="date" runat="server" Text='31' />
    <span><asp:Literal ID="month" runat="server" Text='July' /></span> 
  </div>
 </li>
```

and your code behind file:

```
date.Text = "20";
month.Text = "August";
```

as per suggestion changed label to literal.

Comment: thank you, but it can not save the style of text
http://s23.postimg.org/qktr64z7v/Untitled.png

Comment: you can use asp:Litral control instead of asp:Label in above design